# move_base with own localization

Tags: localization, navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together

This is my first attempt at using the navigation stack. I have written my own node to localize my robot using a laser scanner and kalman fitler,the odometry is not reliable enough. The localization gives me the pose of the robot. I would now like to use move_base with my determined pose to drive to certain goals. I wouldlike, that move_base relies only on my localization, because the odometry is ot reliable enough. How can I tell the move_base node to use my own pose?

Thanks allot in advance!

---------Update--------------
After yout post I looked into AMCL and saw, that this could as well solve my problem. I have a map consisting of four landmarks and I know the starting position. The laser will register at least two of those landmarks, which is sufficient for a localization in 2D (afaik...). The problem is, that the laser will as well register allot of "noise" inside and outside the desired area (people and robots moving). But if I limit the region of interest for amcl to the area without noise, which contains all the landmarks, shouldn't it be possible to use AMCL as it is?
If so, how can I limit the information provided by the topic scan to the region of interest? Can I write a node, which takes the scan informations, eliminates all unneeded scans and passes the filtered data?

P.s.(should i post this as a knew question?)

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59354/move_base-with-own-localization/) by [funas1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4204/funas1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard way to do achieve this is by using tf. Approaches that are able to localize the robot like [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) or [AMCL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) publish the map -> odom transform. If you follow this convention with your localization approach, you should be able to use it as a drop-in replacement for the other mentioned approaches. I did that myself with [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) and it works without problems.

In fact, move_base doesn't care at all which localization approach is used, as it only uses tf to do queries about transforms. See [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) for an overview of coordinate frames for mobile robots. Again, the job of your localization node would be providing the map -> odom transform.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [funas1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4204/funas1/) on 2013-03-27**:
Thank you very much for your answer. So if I understood correctly I just need to provide my pose estimated by the localization node via tf? I will try this give an update. Thanks!